# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' - line 25

Tags: php, syntax-error

```
<?php

if (isset($POST['submit'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$Fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Fname']);
$Lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Lname']);
$Uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Uname']);
$Pword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Pword']);

//ERROR HANDLERS
//Check for empty feilds

if (empty($Fname) || empty($Lname) || empty($Uname) || empty($Pword)) {

  header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
  exit();

} else {

//check if input characters are valid
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $Fname) || (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $Lname)) {

      header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
      exit();
}

else {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofile WHERE userprofile_Uname='$Uname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultcheck > 0) {

      header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
      exit();

    } else {

// hashing the Password

    $hashedPword = password_hash($Pword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //INSERT THE USER INTO THE DATA BASE
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userprofile (Fname, Lname, Uname, Pword) VALUES ('$Fname', '$Lname', '$Uname', '$hashedPword')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sqi);

    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
    exit();

    }
}

}
}
 else {
  header("Location: ../signup.php");
  exit();
}
?>
```

im getting the error when i fill in the form and press sign up according the the error below the error is on line 25 but cannot see the error in my code.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /storage/ssd1/612/4681612/public_html/includes/signup.inc.php on line 25

if anyone has any ideas it would be a great help

many thanks.

Comment: Too many `(` see here `(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $Lname)) {` - tip, use an editor which shows syntax errors.

Comment: could you explain that a bit more as the code you can have sent is the same as mine.

Comment: remove the `(` at the start of `(!preg_match` you have too many count them.

Comment: thank you so much, now i have another problem to deal with only in a coders world